How can I make Firefox or Chrome ignore the system time on Mac OS?
I'm a software engineer trying to test some things. Would appreciate if anyone knows how to do this on Mac OS.

AFAIK, the best you might get within those browsers is to spoof the time zone. In Firefox, there are add-ons that claim to do so, though I have not tried them. There might have been an item in about:config for general.timezone, but it appears to have been removed.

Put your testing environment into a virtual machine, for example UTM or Parallels, and disable time synchronisation with the host/internet.

No need for virtual machines.
If you are testing something manually, e.g. in Chrome, you can change time information temporarily in Dev tools (F12) -> kebab menu icon  -> More tools -> Sensors -> Location.
If you are using an automation tool, it might also have a built-in option for setting timezone. E.g.:

Selenium
Puppeteer

